# Oracle Query Optimization - Difference in Execution Time of 2 Queries

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, query-performance

I was wondering if anyone had a clear explanation of why `Query A` takes hours to complete, while `Query B` is nearly instant.

*Note: Table1 has an index on VarA.*

**Query A:**

```
select count(*) 
  from Table1 
 where VarA in (select A from Table2)
   and VarB in (select B from Table3);
```

**Query B:**

```
Create table tmp1 as select * from Table1 where VarA in (select A from Table2);

select count(*) 
  from tmp1
 where VarA in (select A from Table2)
   and VarB in (select B from Table3);
```

All I've done here is create a temp table which is a subset of `Table1` containing all records matching `VarA` & then run `Query A` against the `temp table`.

Can anyone explain why Oracle wouldn't make similar optimizations and handle the data in a similar manner, resulting in `Query A` having the same execution time as `Query B`?

**Note:** `Query B` refers to both the create table statement AND the select statement. The combined execution time of both statements is nearly instant, while `Query A` is quite slow (takes hours to execute)

Comment: What do you mean by Query B? You don't have a query there, you have a CREATE TABLE statement followed by a query. Are you saying that you are able to create the table AND run Query B and the **total** time is nearly instant?

Comment: Yes - maybe calling it Query B was not the most clear way to do so. The creation of the table & the execution of the query combined were nearly instantaneous.

Comment: Look at the execution plans for both queries. Is there a reason you're using subqueries instead of joins?

Comment: @AlexPoole - regarding your second question... Joins would in general not produce the same answer (if varA is duplicated in Table2, for example). But even if there are no duplicates, **semi**-joins (the technical name for the IN operator as the OP is using) are more efficient than standard joins. In a semi-join, the "matching" from a row from Table1 against rows from Table2 can be stopped as soon as the first match is found. In an actual join that is not permitted. On the contrary, if the OP had used joins when he only needed IN conditions, I would ask why joins! :-)

Comment: My best guess would be that for Query A the system decides to first filter on VarB and fails miserably there for some reason (out of date statistics, strange data, optimal index seemingly being on B and not an A, etc...) before proceeding with filtering on VarA. The second query you pretty much decide that the system needs to filter on VarA first and only afterwards needs to take care of B. The query plan should show this.